# R: Join lists in a loop

Tags: r, list, loops, join

I am trying to do something really simple, but I do not seem to succeed, nor find an answer for this particular problem...

I just want to join lists inside a loop.

Check my MWE.

I have a data frame like this:

```
set.seed(123)
mydf <- data.frame(letters=sample(LETTERS[1:4],20,replace=TRUE), numbers=sample(1:5,20,replace=TRUE))
mydf[] <- lapply(mydf, factor)
> mydf
   letters numbers
1        B       5
2        D       4
3        B       4
4        D       5
5        D       4
6        A       4
7        C       3
8        D       3
9        C       2
10       B       1
11       D       5
12       B       5
13       C       4
14       C       4
15       A       1
16       D       3
17       A       4
18       A       2
19       B       2
20       D       2
```

I make 2 lists out of it (one per column), with a color for each level, as:

```
library(RColorBrewer)

cols1 <- colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(length(levels(mydf[,1])), "Set1"))
myPal1 <- cols1(length(levels(mydf[,1])))
myc1 <- list(myPal1)
names(myc1) <- names(mydf)[1]
names(myc1[[1]]) <- levels(mydf[,1])

cols2 <- colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(length(levels(mydf[,2])), "Set1"))
myPal2 <- cols2(length(levels(mydf[,2])))
myc2 <- list(myPal2)
names(myc2) <- names(mydf)[2]
names(myc2[[1]]) <- levels(mydf[,2])
```

And join them:

```
mycolors1 <- c(myc1, myc2)
> mycolors1
$letters
        A         B         C         D 
"#E41A1C" "#377EB8" "#4DAF4A" "#984EA3" 

$numbers
        1         2         3         4         5 
"#E41A1C" "#377EB8" "#4DAF4A" "#984EA3" "#FF7F00"
```

This `mycolors1` list is exactly the output that I want.

However, if I try to do the exact same inside a loop, I do not get the same:

```
mycolors2 <- list()
for (i in dim(mydf)[2]){
  cols <- colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(length(levels(mydf[,i])), "Set1"))
  myPal <- cols(length(levels(mydf[,i])))
  myc <- list(myPal)
  names(myc) <- names(mydf)[i]
  names(myc[[1]]) <- levels(mydf[,i])
  mycolors2 <- c(mycolors2, myc)
}
> mycolors2
$numbers
        1         2         3         4         5 
"#E41A1C" "#377EB8" "#4DAF4A" "#984EA3" "#FF7F00"
```

What am I doing wrong here? How can I get the same output as before but inside a loop this time (make `mycolors2`==`mycolors1`)?

Comment: `> dim(mydf)[2] [1] 2`. You need `seq_along(mydf)`

Comment: Oh dammit! Why I didn't look at that? should be `for (i in 1:dim(mydf)[2]){` I always have that mistake!

Answer (score 1):

I've been a tad obsessed with avoiding `for` loops in R, and instead taking a cue from Hadley's `purrr` technique of functional programming.

```
set.seed(123)
mydf <- data_frame(letters=sample(LETTERS[1:4],20,replace=TRUE), 
numbers=sample(1:5,20,replace=TRUE))
```

I believe I cleaned up your code, so I hope I retained its original function. Output below to let you know if this is the case.

So, instead of looping, you create a function that makes a vector of colors:

```
uniqueElementsPalette <- function(myvec) {

  myvec <- as_tibble(myvec)

  myc <- myvec %>%
    unique() %>%
    nrow() %>%
    brewer.pal("Set1") %>%
    as_tibble()

  names(myc) <- names(myvec)

  return(myc)
}
```

Let's check that it works:

```
> uniqueElementsPalette(mydf[,1])
# A tibble: 4 x 1
  letters
  <chr>  
1 #E41A1C
2 #377EB8
3 #4DAF4A
4 #984EA3
```

Now, just use `apply`, which runs over every column in your data frame (that's the `2` in the function below), using your function (the last argument).

```
mypalettes <- apply(mydf, 2, uniqueElementsPalette)
```

Resulting in:

```
> mypalettes
$`letters`
# A tibble: 4 x 1
  value  
  <chr>  
1 #E41A1C
2 #377EB8
3 #4DAF4A
4 #984EA3

$numbers
# A tibble: 5 x 1
  value  
  <chr>  
1 #E41A1C
2 #377EB8
3 #4DAF4A
4 #984EA3
5 #FF7F00
```